# I need to use a recursive function to check whether a list is mirrored (the same forwards and reversed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function with three inputs, the list, the index position of the first character of the list and the index position of the last character of the list, which returns `True` if the list is mirrored and `False` if it's not. For the following code

```
def is_mirror(list_to_check, first_position, last_position):
    if len(list_to_check) <= 1 :
        return True
    if list_to_check[first_position] == list_to_check[last_position]:
        return is_mirror(list_to_check, first_position + 1, last_position - 1)
    else :
        return False
```

When I try run the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
print(is_mirror(a, 0, len(a) - 1))
```

I get an error saying

> list index out of range

This should print `True` when run.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

It has to be a recursive function because the task requires me to use a recursive function.

Comment: You are never modifying `first_position` or `last_position` in your recursive call...

Comment: If you are going to be passing slices what is the point of passing indices as well?

Comment: Obviously, this is some sort of exercise to understand recursion.

Comment: Wait, by "I fixed some stuff" do you mean that your **current implementation** is still giving the same error?

Comment: Ok, this is *NOT* a debugging service. Don't keep editing your question with updates and creating this piecemeal. You have logic errors in your function, that is why it always returns `False`. Note, your current implementation never changes the size of `list_to_check` so your condition `len(list_to_check) == 1` can never be `True`

Comment: If your homework is to write a function that takes 3 parameters like that, don't modify the list at all. Check the basis case using the indices, and modify both indices at the recursive call (march them towards each other).

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
l == l[::-1]
```

That will return `False` for

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

and `True`

for

```
l = [1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a memory-efficient Python 3 lazy approach:

```
from itertools import islice

def isPalindrome(x):
    n = len(x)
    return all(i == j for i,j in zip(islice(x,n//2),reversed(x)))
```

This doesn't create any reversed copy and doesn't have more equality tests than needed. On the other hand, `itertools` approaches involve function-call overhead. For smaller lists the simple `x == x[::-1]` approach would be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_mirror(list_to_check, first_position, last_position):
    if last_position <= first_position:
        return True

    return list_to_check[first_position] == list_to_check[last_position] and is_mirror(list_to_check, first_position + 1, last_position - 1)
```

Alright I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Congratulations for figuring it out. The tricky point is how the two indices actually hop over each other in the case of an even number of elements. Note that the first two conditions can be combined as `last_position <= first_position`.